# qt creator mobile widget ui text edit new line?

Tags: qt

i've started a mobile widget project
when a button is pushed the program does some astronomical calculations and then displays the results in a ui->text edit
so, the problem is that the calculations carry out two results
i want every result on a single how can it be done
p.s: i'm using

```
ui->textEdit->setPlainText(text)
```

there are no errors at all
i've tried

```
"/n"
std::endl
```

in the "/n" it write it as is
in std::endl it says:
error:

```
no match for 'operator+' in 'operator+(const char*, const QString&)(((const QString&)((const QString*)(& out1)))) + std::endl'
```

the code is:

```
QString out = "Alt : "+out1+std::endl+"Az : "+out2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the newline try this `'\n'`

Something like `QString out = "Alt : "+out1+'\n'+"Az : "+out2;` should work.

Comment: with single quotes, not with double, to make it a char and not a char* (I'm not sure that the result would be different in this case)